# unauthorized client error in python oauth2

Tags: python, api, oauth-2.0

I am receiving an Unauthorized client error when trying to make an API call to receive an access token

```
import requests, json
import subprocess
import sys
from requests_oauthlib import oauth2_session

authorize_url = 'https://id.xxx.com/connect/authorize'
token_url = 'https://id.xxx.com/connect/token'
redirect_uri = 'httpsxxxlocalhost'
test_api_url = 'https://id.xxxx.com/connect/authorize'
client_id = 'xxxxx'
client_secret = 'xxxxxxxxxxx'
scope = 'read offline_access read_jobad'

authorization_redirect_url = authorize_url + '? 
response_type=code&client_id=' + client_id + '&redirect_uri=' + 
redirect_uri + '&scope=read offline_access read_jobad'
print ('go to the following url on the browser and enter the code from 
the returned url: ')
print ('---  ' + authorization_redirect_url + '  ---')
authorization_code = input()
print(authorization_code)

data = {"client_id":client_id, "client_secret":client_secret, 
    "grant_type":"authorization_code", "code":authorization_code, 
"redirect_uri":redirect_uri}
print(data)

response = requests.post(token_url, data=data)
print(response.json())
```

Not sure what i am doing wrong here (python noob)

Comment: _I am receiving an Unauthorized client error_ When ? On Auth code or on POST ? Can you add more details ? Can you add the full error ? Custom oAuth Auth Provider ? Have you verified ALL url ? Please edit the Question to add more infos.

Comment: Hey max, it occurs during the POST. the full error is '{'error': 'unauthorized_client'}'. OAuth2, and i have verified the url's are correct

Answer (score 0):

In this case you are not managing the `state`.

It would be worthwhile taking inspiration from the `requests_oauthlib` [doco found here](https://requests-oauthlib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/oauth2_workflow.html#backend-application-flow)

IF that doesn't work, or if you need to customise your request, maybe have a look at my code below.

```py
from requests_oauthlib import OAuth2Session
from oauthlib.oauth2 import WebApplicationClient, BackendApplicationClient
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth

client_id = CLIENT_ID
client_secret = CLIENT_SECRET
authorization_base_url = AUTHORIZE_URI
token_url = TOKEN_URI
redirect_uri = REDIRECT_URI
auth = HTTPBasicAuth(client_id, client_secret)
scope = SCOPE

# Create the Authorization URI
# Not included here but store the state in a safe place for later
the_first_session = OAuth2Session(client_id=client_id, redirect_uri=redirect_uri, scope=scope)
authorization_url, state = the_first_session.authorization_url(authorization_base_url)

# Browse to the Authorization URI

# Login and Auth with the OAuth provider

# Now to respond to the callback

the_second_session = OAuth2Session(client_id, state=state)

body = 'grant_type=authorization_code&code=%s&redirect_uri=%s&scope=%s' % (request.GET.get('code'), redirect_uri, scope)
token = the_second_session.fetch_token(token_url, code=request.GET.get('code'), auth=auth, body=body)
```